# Promisifying Node Server code

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, promise, bluebird

Basically I am running into sequencing issue for my node application. I have a requirement to create a chat room.
Three components : 1.) server.js 2.) RoomHandler.js 3.) DBService.js

When the user clicks on createRoom, it should return the roomId generated in database. [This operation consists of 2 mysql parts :

```
 query1 = insert into groupchatroom(room_name,room_description) values('test1','Test room dummy room');

 query2 = select groupchatroomid  from groupchatroom where room_name='test1';
```

Only if 1 suceeds, 2 should get fired.

Here's how the sequence of code goes

When the request comes to server.js :

```
app.post('/createGroupRoom',function(req,res){
var roomData  = JSON.parse(req.query.room);
var roomId=roomHandler.createGroupRoom(roomData.roomName,roomData.roomDesc);
res.json({roomNum: roomId});
});
```

Inside RoomHandler :

```
var that = this;
var p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    that.dbService.executeQuery(query1,resolve,reject);
});
p.then(function()
{
    that.dbService.executeQuery(query2,p.resolve,p.reject);
}).then(function(resultSet){
    //resultSet is always coming as undefined
    if(resultSet[0] && resultSet[0].id_groupchatroom)
    {
        console.log("Created groupRoom "+resultSet[0].id_groupchatroom);
        return resultSet[0].id_groupchatroom;
    }
}).catch(function(err){}).catch(function(err){; });
```

Inside DBService :

```
 DBService.prototype.executeQuery = function(query,callback,callbackerr){
  console.log("Query to DB : "+query);
    var that = this;
    this.pool.getConnectionAsync().then(function(connection){
        that.Promise.promisifyAll(connection);
        connection.queryAsync(query).then(function(resultSet){
            connection.release();
            callback(resultSet);
        }).catch(function(err){
            connection.release();
            callbackerr(err);
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        connection.release();
        callbackerr(err);
    });
```

} ;

I am not able to get the resultSet of the second query in the second then chain of Promise. Moreover it always gives the following error, callback is not a function at the same place. May be p.resolve is not a function. But I am clueless how to structure the above code. If it was Java application, it would have been as simple as below.

server.java :

```
 roomHandler.createRoom(roomData,httpReq,httpResp);
```

RoomHandler.java :

```
 public void createRoom(Room roomData, HttpRequest req, HttpResponse res)
 if(dbService.executeQuery(query1))
 {
  rs = dbService.executeQuery(query2);
  if(rs!=null)
    res.end(rs.next());         

 }
```

I am not sure whether I am trying to over promisify the code here !! .But its better to sequence the code from start. Any help/tutorial would be appreciated.

Comment: missing return in `that.dbService.e..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code has couple of issues other than the missing return in the promise chain, for starters, stop wrapping promises with promises:

```
DBService.prototype.executeQuery = function(query){
 console.log("Query to DB : "+query);
   var that = this, connection;
   return this.pool.getConnectionAsync().then(function(_connection){
       connection = that.Promise.promisifyAll(_connection);
       return connection.queryAsync(query);
   }).then(function(resultSet){
       connection.release();
       return resultSet;
   }).catch(function(err){
       if(connection)  connection.release();
       throw err;
   });
}
```

and RoomHandler code would be something like:

```
var that = this;
return this.dbService.executeQuery(query1).then(function(){
   return that.dbService.executeQuery(query2);
}).then(function(resultSet){
    //resultSet is always coming as undefined
    if(resultSet[0] && resultSet[0].id_groupchatroom)
    {
        console.log("Created groupRoom "+resultSet[0].id_groupchatroom);
        return resultSet[0].id_groupchatroom;
    }
}).catch(function(err){});
```

**Edit:**

your server.js would be something like:

```
app.post('/createGroupRoom',function(req,res){
  var roomData  = JSON.parse(req.query.room);
  roomHandler.createGroupRoom(roomData.roomName,roomData.roomDesc)
    .then(function(roomId){
      res.json({roomNum: roomId})
    });
});
```

Comment: So , suppose we have to go for executing multiple queries, I guess we can keep on "then"ing like you mentioned above. The code of the roomHandler you mentioned would have to be called within a promise in server.js or somewhere right ?.. because if i dont wrap the roomHandler code you wrote within a promise in server.js, it will send undefined in the response (because Node\javascript is turn based)........... I understood your point of chaining returns. If I include your roomHandler code within a promise in server.js ...who will call the resolve ? ...Sorry for being ignorant.

Comment: So, Is there no need to create Promise at all ? Also one more doubt: roomHandler code returns id_groupchatroom (or) Promise ??

Comment: It returns promise that resolves to the id of the chatroom

Comment: Thank you. I hope the following code change wont make any difference in the above 3 snippets you gave. var tobeReturned = this.XXXXXXX.then().then().......catch().catch()...... ; return tobeReturned;  Also ... looks like at many places, instead of returning raw values like boolean, string etc, .....we have to replace it with Promise.resolve(rawValue);